# IXMLHTTPRequest2

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8

I am working on a Win Phone 8 application that is using IXMLHTTPRequest2 to perform HTTP requests.  During one part of the request, I need to get out the Cookie values.

I am trying to use the GetCookie method, to get all of the cookies, but it does not seem to be returning any values (I verified in Fiddler that the response does contain a Set-Cookie header).

```
XHR_COOKIE *cookies = NULL;
ULONG cCookies = 0;
int cookieFlags = -1;
m_xhr->GetCookie(m_Url, NULL, cookieFlags, &cCookies, &cookies);
```

Comment: did you ever find a resolution here?  i'm in the same boat as you were, and the amount of useful documentation/examples for cookie handling is underwhelming...

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass in some legit cookieFlags: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn384116(v=vs.85).aspx